# MS Access: Designing a Report template

Tags: ms-access, report

I have designed a few Reports based on queries in Access to display data in specific ways with paragraphs of texts just like a letter. Is there a way to save these designs as templates so that in future, users who enter new data are able to generate reports based on my designed format?

Comment: These 'paragraphs of text' are just textboxes or labels with static text, not data from tables? You want to allow users to modify this text? If variable info does not come from tables then has to be by reference to UNBOUND controls on a form where users type input which means the form has to remain open when the report runs. If you don't save this input to a table then the report is hardly reproducible and only documentation would be a hard copy print.

Comment: Review http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html, pay special note to the line halfway down starting with "To use the search results for a report,..."

Comment: I presume, that two tables are needed. The original for the data and a new second one for the "design" of the report? ie: other titles, captions, remarks and so on. Another possibility would be to generate several versions of the original report and have the user chose one depending on the situation.

Comment: The "paragraphs of text" are labels with static text. What I did was create a report using the Report Wizard based on an established query. What I did was to drag the result boxes around to fit them into paragraphs.